# AngularJS orderBy date not ordering correctly

Tags: angularjs

I have written a function in `php` to get a list of objects with added_date as a field in each of them. I have used date filter to display date in `dd-MMM-yyyy` format. Since added_date is in string format, I tried converting it into Date object, but the output is still not ordered. Can someone help me understand what I might be missing here?

Controller code :

```
$scope.getData = function () {
  TestService.getData($scope.id).then(function (data) {
    if(data){
      $scope.testList = angular.copy(_.map(data.testArray, function (testInputs) {
        _.each(testInputs, function (testInput, key) {
          testInput.added_date = new Date(testInput.added_date);  
        });
        return testInputs;
      }));
    }
  });
};
```

HTML :

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="(pIndex, testInputs) in testList  | orderBy: $parent.orderBy: reverse">
```

```
<td rowspan="{{testInputs.length}}" data-ng-if="($index == 0)"><b>{{testInput.added_date | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</b></td>
```

Output :

```
19-May-2020
20-May-2020
07-Apr-2020
01-Jun-2020
04-Jun-2020
```

Desired Output :

```
07-Apr-2020
19-May-2020
20-May-2020
01-Jun-2020
04-Jun-2020
```

`data.testArray` is grouped on `added_date`. Converting date to milliseconds using `strtotime`, when grouping. It looks like this :

```
{
    "institution": "ins1",
    "details": [
        [
            {
                "id": "11",
                "added_date": 1591228800000,
                "subject": "subject1",
                "grade": "A"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": "22",
                "added_date": 1590969600000,
                "subject": "subject2",
                "grade": "A"
            },
            {
                "id": "33",
                "added_date": 1590969600000,
                "subject": "subject3",
                "grade": "A+"
            },
            {
                "id": "44",
                "added_date": 1590969600000,
                "subject": "subject4",
                "grade": "B+"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

TIA!

Comment: can you post an example of `data.testArray`

Comment: Edited the question to include data.testArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to order by key:

```
<body 
   data-ng-repeat="(pIndex, testInput) in testList  | orderBy: 'added_date'">
```

With reverse add `-`:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="(pIndex, testInput) in testList  | orderBy: '-added_date'">
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aw56HZwI6rVCm6F0)</kbd>

Comment: The issue I am facing when using `-` for reverse is, I am not able to access the `added_date` field directly. The field is actually `testInput.added_date`.

Comment: The dates are getting sorted, but the order is not quite right.

Comment: @luna well, the structure is different now, list inside a list. So you cannot order it as is. Why do not convert to basic list

Comment: Converted to basic list. Able to access added_date directly now. Thanks a lot, @Maxim Shoustin.